# can't find element although Xpath work selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH))
driver.get("https://jklm.fun/****")

#WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='syllable']"))))

driver.implicitly_wait(20)
word = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='syllable']").text
print(word)
```

> Error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no
> such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='syllable']"}

I have the following code written in python, and i am trying get the generated word though the xpath is right, the program can't find the element from some reason.
Can you help me? (I tried removing the service parameter and it still doesn't work)

Part of the html code:

```
<div class="canvasArea">
        <canvas width="995" height="807"></canvas>
        <div class="quickRules">
          <div class="summary"><span class="dictionary">English</span> (<span class="wordsPerPrompt">min. 10</span> <span data-text="wpp">wpp</span>)</div>
          <button class="toggleRules">Show rules</button>
        </div>

        <div class="round">
          <div class="syllable">yt</div>
        </div>
        <div class="seating" hidden="">
          <div class="lastRound">
            <div class="winnerPicture">
              <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
              <div class="medal"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="winnerNickname">hog rider</div>
            <div data-text="wonTheLastRound">won the last round!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you check if the element is inside a frame or shadow-dom?

Comment: it's inside alot of div elements

Comment: Please, provide a link to the website or part of the html-code that reveals the element.

Comment: https://jklm.fun/ you need to enter a game and inspect the generated word in the middle of the page(i can't send images because of my reputation points)

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML